# How to highlight a table row using style binding?

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I need to show a details view based on a selected row in a table. I would like to show which row is currently selected in the table. Is it possible to do this with the 'style' binding?

I've created a [JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrzFx/8/) with some code illustrating the idea...or lack of, since it currently all rows change color on row click. Here's the code:

```html
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Sales</th>
       <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  <tbody data-bind='template: { name: "fieldTemplate", foreach: viewModel.items}'></tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/html" id="fieldTemplate">
    <tr >
         <td> ${name}</td>
         <td>${sales}</td>
         <td>${price}</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

And this is the Javascript:

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
            { name: "Well-Travelled Kitten", sales: 352, price: 75.95 },
            { name: "Speedy Coyote", sales: 89, price: 190.00 },
            { name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 152, price: 25.00 },
            { name: "Indifferent Monkey", sales: 1, price: 99.95 },
            { name: "Brooding Dragon", sales: 0, price: 6350 },
            { name: "Ingenious Tadpole", sales: 39450, price: 0.35 },
            { name: "Optimistic Snail", sales: 420, price: 1.50 }
        ])
};
```

So I think I need a reference to the current row, or adding a style attribute to my item and then bind to this, and then change in the click event. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to bind a click event to each row of the table. Once a row is clicked. then in the event handler you can change the color of the selected row + you can show the new details

something like this > http://jsfiddle.net/wrzFx/11/

Comment: Looks great!, but how do I get the selected 'ko.observable' in the jquery event handler? I liked the 'data-bind="click: function() { viewModel.showItem($data) }'. And i'm trying to wrap my head around Knockout and Jquery at the same time ;)

Comment: ok my bad you can use them in conjunction.. `class="clickableRow" data-bind="click: function() { viewModel.showItem($data) }"`

Answer (score 2):

I would bind a selection event on a table row via jQuery `live` events. Inside the listener I would change the value of `selectedRow` attribute in your `viewModel`

That might not sound a Knockout way to do things but as long as it works I'm ok with it.

BTW, I can't get jQuery templates running inside jsFiddle for some reason.

Comment: add this line to his jsfiddle > `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`

Comment: @nEEbz, ouch! Didn't notice. Your solution is exactly what I was implied.